# How to use front/gutenberg-js within a react app?

Tags: javascript, wordpress-gutenberg

I have already created a react app by using create-react-app cli. The application is running fine. I have to use guttenberg editor which is there in wordpress 5.

There is a javascript only version available, in https://github.com/front/gutenberg-js. 
The problem is when ever I am trying to domReady, editPost these by using following import statement

```
import { domReady, editPost } from '@frontkom/gutenberg-js';
```

My react application is not working,

Below is the exception

```
gutenberg-js.js:104 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createContext' of undefined
    at Module.push../node_modules/@frontkom/gutenberg-js/build/js/gutenberg-js.js (gutenberg-js.js:104)
    at n (gutenberg-js.js:17)
    at Module.push../node_modules/@frontkom/gutenberg-js/build/js/gutenberg-js.js (gutenberg-js.js:45274)
    at n (gutenberg-js.js:17)
    at push../node_modules/@frontkom/gutenberg-js/build/js/gutenberg-js.js (gutenberg-js.js:51)
    at Object../node_modules/@frontkom/gutenberg-js/build/js/gutenberg-js.js (gutenberg-js.js:52)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
    at fn (bootstrap:149)
    at Module../src/components/PageEditor.js (HomeComponent.js:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
    at fn (bootstrap:149)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.css?f3f6:45)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
    at fn (bootstrap:149)
    at Object.0 (store.js:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:781)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
```

The expectation is import should work.